# Rust language - Drop & Borrow checker

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
fn testing(myptr :&mut Box<i32>) {
    println!("Fn is called: {}",myptr);
    *myptr=Box::new(300);
    println!("Inside: {}",myptr);
    *myptr=Box::new(0);
    println!("Inside: {}",myptr);
    drop(myptr);
}

fn main() {
    let mut myptr = Box::new(100);
    println!("Before Func: {}",myptr);
    testing(&mut myptr);
    println!("From Main: {}",myptr);
}
```

output

```
Before Func: 100
Fn is called: 100
Inside: 300
Inside: 0
From Main: 0
```

since i have invoked drop function i am expecting the value shouldn't be accessible even from main function but thats not happing. not able to understand why. Need help in understanding who is owning ownership and why drop function is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `drop(myptr)` in this context does not drop the `Box<i32>` it only drops the *reference*, which is effectively a no-op. You cannot drop something via a reference since it doesn't *own* the value. And what would the `"From Main:"` line print?

If you want `myptr` to be dropped by `testing()`, then you will have to take ownership of it:

```
fn testing(myptr: Box<i32>) {
    // myptr will be destroyed at the end of the scope
}

fn main() {
    let myptr = Box::new(100);
    testing(myptr);

    // attempting to use it afterwards will yield a compiler error
    // println!("From Main: {}", myptr);
}
```

If you want `testing()` to "nullify" `myptr`, use an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html):

```
fn testing(myptr: &mut Option<Box<i32>>) {
    *myptr = None;
}

fn main() {
    let mut myptr = Some(Box::new(100));
    println!("Before Func: {:?}", myptr); // prints "Some(100)"
    testing(&mut myptr);
    println!("From Main: {:?}", myptr); // prints "None"
}
```